# How to properly use BERT in keras for classification

Tags: keras, deep-learning, word-embedding

I am having an issue with using BERT for classification of text within my database. Previously, I have used GLoVE and ELMo that work quite ok. Also Random forests give me quite good F1-scores (over 0.85), however, when using BERT, I am stuck around 0.55. I was trying to modify learning rate for Adam optimizer, used anything between 0.001 to 0.000001, but nothing really helps.

This is my code: https://github.com/EuropeanSocialInnovationDatabase/ESID-main/blob/development/TextMining/Classifiers/DatabaseWithKickStarter/NNClassifierTest2.py

If anyone can pin the problem down, I would be really grateful.

Comment: Did you try the default LR of 2*10^-5 ?? for about 3 epochs?

Comment: Yes, I did. sparse_categorical_accuracy is still around 0.56-0.57. Loss goes down to 0.3581, but still quite low. When I use ELMo embedding and same dense network, I get F1-scores of 0.89.

Comment: Change `n_fine_tune_layers=48` to `10`